# Android Paging (3) load all pages at once

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-paging-3

I'm using the Android Paging 3 library in my project in order to load my data page by page. In this project, I'm not using database which means I'm using `network only requests`. The problem is that instead of loading pages based on the user scroll, it loads all pages at first. here is the code I'm using for the paging part of my project:

My RxPagingSource class:

```
class ReviewPagingSource constructor(
    private val network: Network,
    private val filter: ReviewFilter,
    private val config: Config,
    private val cacheFirstResponse: Boolean
) : RxPagingSource<Int, Review>() {

    override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<Int>): Single<LoadResult<Int, Review>> {
        return network.getReviews(
            filter.copy(page = (params.key ?: 0) , pageSize = params.loadSize),
            config,
            cacheFirstResponse
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { toLoadResultPage(it, params) }
            .onErrorResumeNext {
                when (it) {
                    is TimeoutException,
                    is NoInternetException, is NetworkException, is UnexpectedResponseException -> Single.just(
                        LoadResult.Error(it)
                    )
                    else -> Single.error(it)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun toLoadResultPage(
        response: DataResponse<Review>,
        params: LoadParams<Int>
    ): LoadResult<Int, Review> {
        val page = params.key ?: 0
        return LoadResult.Page(
            response.results!!,
            if (page <= 0) null else page - 1,
            if (response.count ?: response.results?.count() ?: 0 < params.loadSize) null else page + 1,
            LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED,
            LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED
        )
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Review>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { state.closestPageToPosition(it) }?.nextKey
    }
}
```

My Pager is:

```
Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 5, initialLoadSize = 5,)) 
    { ReviewPagingSource(network, filter, config, true) }
    .flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Related Gradle Part:

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-alpha13"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava3:3.0.0-alpha13"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By any chance are you using this in a nested scrolling scenario? What does your layout look like?

Comment: yes, I use NestedScrollView as the parent of my recycler view and now I can see this where my problem begins. Thank you @dlam

Comment: No problem - in the nested scrolling case you must be careful not to give RV an infinite height as otherwise it will try to layout / load all items. If you're not able to use a well-defined height, you could also consider trying to use transformations like .flatMap(), .insertSeparators or use ConcatAdapter in place of nested scroll layout.

Comment: @dlam can you explain more on the solution. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: If you give RV an infinite height, it will try to bind every item because it thinks every item is visible. Nested scrolling is just not a supported use-case, you need to give RV a finite / bounded height. (or width, depending on scroll direction)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this `recipeId` data type was long, but when I changed it to string it works fine. Then, instead of `NestedScrollView` use `SmartNestedScrollview`

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_recipe")
data class RecipeList(
        @PrimaryKey
        @field:SerializedName("recipe_id") var recipeId : String,
        @field:SerializedName("title") var title: String? = null,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If Your RecyclerView has wrap content for height change it to match parent or `0dp`